# Translating python RSA encryption algorithm to JS

Tags: javascript, python, encryption, rsa

The title isn't the best because it sounds like I want to build my own RSA encryption algorithm in JS, but let me explain.

I want to authenticate with Steam servers. 4 post requests are made to 2 urls, the main url for this post is https://store.steampowered.com/login/getrsakey
It returns 3 important things being an RSA timestamp, a modulus and an exponent. I won't post the data here because I'm unsure whether it contains anything important but it's easy to get (Provide your steam username as `username` and `Date.now() * 1000` under `donotcache`. Add this to a form data and make a POST request to the url)

I found a [python script](https://gist.github.com/maxisoft/8364262) on github which implements logging into steam. This is the code that I want to convert into JS:

```
mod = long(str(data["publickey_mod"]), 16)
exp = long(str(data["publickey_exp"]), 16)
rsa = RSA.construct((mod, exp))
cipher = PKCS1_v1_5.new(rsa)
print base64.b64encode(cipher.encrypt(passwd))
```

It uses the data from the response to construct an RSA key. Creates a `PKCS1_v1_5` cipher from that key and then encrypts the password. I have already NodeRSA but for some reason it [breaks within a promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66304445/nodersa-causing-promise-to-jump-to-catch-function). Today, I came [this](https://github.com/junkurihara/jscu/tree/master/packages/js-crypto-rsa#readme) crypto library in which I tried the example (the `rsa.sign` example because I couldn't pass in the `RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5` name for `rsa.encrypt`) passing in firstly just the plain `publickey_mod` and `publickey_exp` from the url but it errored:

```
Error: UnsupportedEnvironment: Cannot create a key using the specified key usages.
```

I also tried:

```
const n = Buffer.from(mod, "hex");
const e = Buffer.from(exp, 0);
```

which I got from a NodeRSA example. This also errors:

```
Error: UnsupportedEnvironment: The JWK member "n" could not be base64url decoded or contained padding
```

It's proving quite difficult to encrypt this password and I was wondering if anyone could provide some help?

Answer (score 0):

So I tried translating it and I did. Turns out the when converting the modulus from hex to an integer, it is massive so JS does not support it at all. I tried the `bigInt` library but I soon gave up on it because I couldn't be bothered to rewrite everything.

I decided I'd look harder to see if others had tried this and I found an authentication script which works in a different way. It creates an RSA PEM which is then fed into NodeRSA instead of constructing a key from a tuple of the modulus and exponent, like in python.
This is the function: https://github.com/winauth/SteamAuth/blob/62e08de0159d208554a92283bba3458021479335/index.js#L924